# Command running in kubernetes hangs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, clickhouse

I need to run a command in clickhouse database in kubernetes.

When I try it with docker it works ok:

`docker run -it yandex/clickhouse-client -h 172.19.0.1  --database=test --query="SYSTEM RELOAD DICTIONARIES"`

but when I run it in kub:

```
kubectl run  --quiet -it --rm  clickhouse-client --image=yandex/clickhouse-client -- -h clickhouse-server  --database=test --query="SYSTEM RELOAD DICTIONARIES"
```

Second command hangs.
The pod is in CrashLoopBackOff with Back-off restarting failed container/
And the logs of container contains the result of query.

Why do the result not flushed to tty?

This command works for me:

`kubectl run busybox --quiet -it --rm --restart=Never --image=busybox -- nslookup foobar`

What is the difference with click-house client?

Comment: could you ensure `clickhouse-server` DNS lookup works fine inside your kubernetes cluster?
please run
`kubectl run busybox --quiet -it --rm --restart=Never --image=busybox -- nslookup clickhouse-server`

Comment: if you remove `--quiet` option, maybe you can see error message which showed by `clickhouse-client`

Comment: @ogbofjnr as your issue is resolved and you pointed it it in the comments under the answers I kindly ask you to create an answer apart from the comments with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

@ogbofjnr this is likely because the pod is getting killed as soon as your query is done. Kubernetes will restart the pod, and it will again die after executing the query. This is why you are seeing a restart loop.

For busy box, the entrypoint is a long running command like sleep 3600 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/testdata/recursive/pod/pod/busybox.yaml#L10-L12.

You should either try something similar or try Kubernetes cron job if the idea is to run the query on a schedule.

Comment: Turned out the issue in kub version, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589468/why-tty-hangs-after-command-is-finished

Answer (score 0):

Your pod are being killed as soon it's running, I suggest you create your pod using file yaml and add command on in your yaml file then verify your clickhouse-server in DNS resolver

```
---
......
      containers:
      - name: clickhouse-client
        image: yandex/clickhouse-client
        command:
          - "-h"
          - "clickhouse-server"
          - "--database=test"
          - "--query='SYSTEM RELOAD DICTIONARIES'"
        resources: {}
........
---
```

Comment: turned out the issue is in kub version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589468/why-tty-hangs-after-command-is-finished