# Why tty hangs after command is finished?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to run a command like this:

`kubectl run busybox  -it --rm --restart=Never --image=busybox --command -- sh -c "env"`

Expected to run command and delete pod.
It prints the variables, but then terminal freezes, although pod is in completed state, but --rm not works.

Same thing works ok with docker:

`docker run -it --rm busybox  sh -c "env"`

Comment: What is your kubernetes version `$ kubectl version --short` ?

Comment: Could you try with `--tty` (allocate a TTY for each container in the Pod) instead of `-it` (interactive mode) ?

Comment: @KamolHasan , `Client Version: v1.16.0
Server Version: v1.14.3`

Comment: @AndD, isn't -i and -tty the same? I see in help `  -t, --tty=false: Allocated a TTY for each container in the pod. ` I've tried, same result.

Comment: @ogbofjnr, I'm on `Client Version: v1.18.3 Server Version: v1.16.9`, it works as expected.  `... ... pod "busybox" deleted`

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is a bug, that gets fixed.